# Separate C_Sign call from C_Generate

Tags: c, cryptography, pkcs#11

I'm implementing pkcs11 with C code, and trying to implement a simple generate, sign, verify workflow. The flow works when I make a single call to my pkcs11 driver for everything. However, I'm trying to decouple these calls, so that I may be able to generate a key, use it at a later stage for a separate c_sign or c_verify call.

My main problem is that the c_sign call requires a CK_OBJECT_HANDLE parameter for the Private Key handle, but I don't know how to retrieve this at a later stage. The reason it works on the single "generate -> sign -> verify" flow is that the handle is still in memory from the generate call, making it easily accessible on the subsequent calls.

My generate call looks like this:

```
C_GenerateKeyPair(hSession, &mechanism, 
                  publicKeyTemplate, 
                  sizeof(publicKeyTemplate)/sizeof(CK_ATTRIBUTE), 
                  privateKeyTemplate, 
                  sizeof(privateKeyTemplate)/sizeof(CK_ATTRIBUTE), 
                  phPublicKey, phPrivateKey);
```

where `phPublicKey` and `phPrivateKey` are where the handles are then stored...

The subsequent sign function expects a `hPrivateKey` parameter, for the privKey I want to sign with.

Comment: Isn't the parameter stored in whatever `phPrivateKey` points to? What's preventing you from keeping it in memory as long as you need it?

Comment: In the later stage you probably need to retrieve your object handles via `C_FindObjectsInit`-`C_FindObjects`-`C_FindObjectsFinal` functions...Remember to use sane (and unique) labels for your generated objects...Good luck with your project!

Comment: I'd recommend that you share a larger part of your code so people can understand what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A handle is tied to a session. In a new session, the handle is not valid anymore. To maintain a reference to a key, you need to give it some unique name. There are two ways to do that:

- Any [object in storage](http://docs.oasis-open.org/pkcs11/pkcs11-base/v2.40/os/pkcs11-base-v2.40-os.html#_Toc319314009) can have a `CKA_LABEL` attribute whose value is a printable string.
- Any [key object](http://docs.oasis-open.org/pkcs11/pkcs11-base/v2.40/os/pkcs11-base-v2.40-os.html#_Ref323111513) can have a `CKA_ID` attribute whose value is a byte array.

Give your key a unique id or label. To open it later, you need to search for it. It's the only way: PKCS#11 doesn't have a way to directly open a key by name! You need to search for an object with the correct id/label, and if that attribute is unique, you know that the first one you find is the right one. It's ok (and really more convenient) to give the public key and the private key in a matching key pair the same id/label; specify which one you want through the class attribute when you search for it.

Creation:

```
CK_BYTE id[] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04};
int generate_key(CK_SESSION_HANDLE hSession, …)
{
    CK_BBOOL ck_true = CK_TRUE;
    CK_ATTRIBUTE publicKeyTemplate[] = {
        {CKA_TOKEN, &ck_true, sizeof(ck_true)},
        {CKA_ID, id, sizeof(id)},
        …
    };
    CK_ATTRIBUTE privateKeyTemplate[] = {
        {CKA_TOKEN, &ck_true, sizeof(ck_true)},
        {CKA_ID, id, sizeof(id)},
        …
    };
    CK_MECHANISM mechanism = …;
    CK_OBJECT_HANDLE hPublicKey = CK_INVALID_HANDLE;
    CK_OBJECT_HANDLE hPrivateKey = CK_INVALID_HANDLE;
    C_GenerateKeyPair(hSession, &mechanism, 
                      publicKeyTemplate, 
                      sizeof(publicKeyTemplate)/sizeof(CK_ATTRIBUTE), 
                      privateKeyTemplate, 
                      sizeof(privateKeyTemplate)/sizeof(CK_ATTRIBUTE), 
                      &hPublicKey, &hPrivateKey);
}
```

Use (most error checking omitted):

```
CK_BYTE id[] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04}; // same as when creating the key
int sign_stuff(CK_SESSION_HANDLE hSession, ) {
    CK_OBJECT_CLASS cko_private_key = CKO_PRIVATE_KEY;
    CK_ATTRIBUTE privateKeyTemplate[] = {
        {CKA_ID, id, sizeof(id)},
        {CKA_CLASS, cko_private_key, sizeof(cko_private_key)},
    };
    C_FindObjectsInit(hSession,
                      privateKeyTemplate, sizeof(privateKeyTemplate)/sizeof(*privateKeyTemplate));
    CK_OBJECT_HANDLE hPrivateKey = CK_INVALID_HANDLE;
    CK_ULONG count = 0;
    C_FindObjects(hSession, &hPrivateKey, 1, &count);
    C_FindObjectsFinal(hSession);
    if (count == 0)
        return ERROR_KEY_NOT_FOUND;
    CK_MECHANISM mechanism = …;
    C_SignInit(hSession, &mechanism, hPrivateKey);
    …
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. You've also covered the question I was going to ask next. Because when I tried C_FindObjects I got more than 1 keys, which makes sense, it being a key-pair.. So I got an `Invalid Key Type` error trying to sign with the public key since I couldn't know which one to use from the array it returned :)  So the `CK_OBJECT_CLASS` helped!